# Debugging in Eclipse PDT (Xdebug) with ionCube encoded php scritps

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-pdt, ioncube

I am using the latest Eclipse PDT with Xdebug to debug my development website on a Windows PC with XAMPP (Apache2.4 and MySQL) and PHP version 5.6.33.

php.ini contains the following lines:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

[XDebug]
zend_extension = "ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll"
zend_extension = "php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
```

PHP Thread Safe is enabled.

The site contains a module that needs ionCube to run an encoded php script. It runs okay in Eclipse but it falls over (hangs) when I run the debugger. I have confirmed that it hangs when I step into the encoded script.

Some Stack Overflow contributors have said that Xdebug can't handle ionCube encoded scripts, but those posts were quite old. I'm running Xdebug 2.5.5 for PHP 5.6. Is it supposed to be able handle ionCube encoded php scripts? If not, should I change to Zend debugger?

Comment: It's a deficiency in Xdebug, but if you contact Derick perhaps he can give assistance.

Comment: I have discovered the easiest thing to do is to disable the ioncube module (CDSEO Pro) via an SQL patch. Thanks to the BCSEngineering knowledgebase article https://support.bcsengineering.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/86/17/how-can-i-disable-cdseo-without-accessing-the-cdseo-admin-section